# Stop and continue loop by using boolean flag for traffic light

Tags: nodemcu

By using boolean and flag, I can now control the green light but the program cannot repeat or loop the sequence for traffic light from red to yellow to green. If I don't use flag, the sequence red-yellow-green LED can be looped but I can't control and trigger green light on app.

My current project also serial communicate from NodeMCU to Arduino.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial nodemcu(2,3);
long int data;

boolean start = true;        

void setup() {
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);//greenbulb
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);//yellowbulb
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);//redbulb

Serial.begin(9600);
nodemcu.begin(9600);

}

void changeLights()
{
  digitalWrite(7,LOW);// greenbulb
  digitalWrite(8,LOW); // yellowbulb
  digitalWrite(9,HIGH);// redbulb
  delay(7000);

  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);// greenbulb
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);// yellowbulb
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);// redbulb
  delay(5000);

  digitalWrite(7,LOW);// greenbulb
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);// yellowbulb
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);// redbulb
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);// greenbulb
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);// yellowbulb
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);// redbulb
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(7,LOW);// greenbulb
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);// yellowbulb
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);// redbulb
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);// greenbulb
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);// yellowbulb
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);// redbulb
  delay(1000);

  digitalWrite(7,LOW);// greenbulb
  digitalWrite(8,HIGH);// yellowbulb
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);// redbulb
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {

if ( nodemcu.available() > 0 )
{
  data = nodemcu.parseInt();
  delay(100);
  Serial.println(data);

      if (( data == 10) && (start == true)){           
           changeLights();
            start = false;
      }

      if (( data == 11) && (start == false)){           
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);
      digitalWrite(8, LOW);
            start = true;
      }
}  
}
```

Comment: see the BlinkWithoutDelay example

Comment: tip: `if (start)` is same as `if (start == true)`  .........    `if (!start)` is same as `if (start == false)`   .............. less typing and less redundancy

Comment: What you *really* want is a [Finite State Machine](https://majenko.co.uk/blog/finite-state-machine).

Comment: you have a bunch of useless code in your program .... why are you making pin 8 LOW a multiple times in a row? .... you only have to do it once .... same goes for the other pins

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer (that is looking at the BlinkWithoutDelay as Juraj mentioned), but I want to provide a way how to greatly reduce your program and use this method in future.

You are repeating

```
digitalWrite(7,LOW);// greenbulb
digitalWrite(8,HIGH);// yellowbulb
digitalWrite(9,LOW);// redbulb
delay(2000);
```

A lot, with variations of LOW/HIGH and the delay time. Instead, use a function that has parameters:

```
void changeLight(int green, int yellow, int red, int delayTime)
{
    digitalWrite(7, green);
    digitalWrite(8, yellow);
    digitalWrite(9, red);
    delay(delayTime);
}
```

And you can call it by

changeLight(LOW, HIGH, LOW, 2000);

You can do this for all of the 4 line repeats.